# How to populate a custom uitableview from a textfield

Tags: objective-c

I created three textfields food name, food quantity, sodium amount. When I click the submit button I'd like to update a tableview with the data from the textfields.  I created an NSObject as well as established logs to show the data is being saved from the textfield and the submit will move to the tableview but I can't get the data from the textfield to display

```
@interface FoodContents : NSObject
{
    NSString *myFoodName;
    NSString *myFoodQuanity;
    NSString *mySodiumAmount;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * myFoodName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * myFoodQuanity;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * mySodiumAmount;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)foods quanity:(NSString *)foodCount salt:(NSString           *)saltAmount;



- (IBAction)submitOnClick:(id)sender
{

 FoodContents *test = [[FoodContents alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString       stringWithFormat:@"%@",   foodName.text] quanity:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",foodQuanity]   salt:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sodiumAmount.text]];
[textfieldData addObject:test];
NSLog(@"%@", textfieldData);

FoodListViewController * third_viewController = [[FoodListViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"FoodListViewController" bundle:nil];
  if (third_viewController != nil)
{
    third_viewController.foodDetails = test;
    //[self.textfieldData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",     self.foodName.text]];
    //[self.textfieldData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.foodQuanity.text]];
    //[self.textfieldData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.sodiumAmount.text]];

    NSLog(@"%@",textfieldData);
    [self presentViewController:third_viewController animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

}

Comment: Let's see your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    CustomCellViewController *cell = (CustomCellViewController *)
    [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   
    if (cell != nil)
    {
        cell.foodNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text]
        
    }
    
    return cell;

Comment: Have you initialized your `textfieldData` array?

Comment: Yes I did in the viewDidLoad

Comment: textfieldData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *myTextfieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //self.textfieldData = myTextfieldArray;